# Checkbox column not updating when checked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

Here is the code:

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Prototype.Forms.UserForm"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prototype.Forms"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="MainGrid">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#:

```
public partial class UserForm : UserControl
    {

        public UserForm(IList <Element> list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add(" ",typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add("Iteration");
            dt.Columns.Add("View name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Type");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.NewRow();

                r[1] = i.ToString();
                r[2] = list[i].Name;
                r[3] = "some element type";

                dt.Rows.Add(r);
            }

            MainGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            MainGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(CellClick);
        }

        private void CellClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
```

So the problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to get multiple checkboxes to be checked. As soon as I try to check a second checkbox the previously checked box becomes unchecked.

The mouse button event was a failed attempt to try to get checkedboxes to remain checked but failed.

Comment: I've removed your C# and WPF tags from your question title as per [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Can you describe how to reproduce your problem? I'm not seeing it in the code you've provided.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your corresponding xaml code

Comment: @dontbyteme: also what is happening inside `CellClick()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespace or add a column name for the checkbox column:

```
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(bool));
```

> If null or an empty string ("") is passed in for the name, a default name ("Column1", 
>   "Column2", and so on) is given to the column. [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumnCollection_Add_System_String_System_Type_)

There seems to be a problem with a whitespace as the columns name.